# Cleaner way to assign NaNs in cells below the lower-left to upper-right diagonal of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I don't know the exact terminology of what I'm looking to do so apologies if I'm not describing the desired results properly. Example below to show what I mean that should make it clear.

Also, I do have a solution that is working, but it's super clunky. I'm hoping someone can help me find a much cleaner way to do this.

**The Issue:**

I am trying to take a dataframe of values, like this (it doesn't matter what the values are but note the columns are integers increasing from 0 to whatever):

```
In  [1]: a = np.random.randint(0,10,(5,5))
In  [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(a, index=['A','B','C','D','E'],columns=[x for x in range(5)])
In  [3]: df
Out [3]:
    0   1   2   3   4
A   0   8   9   4   5
B   3   4   5   0   1
C   8   5   5   4   1
D   8   5   3   8   3
E   7   2   6   7   2
```

**Desired result:**

Then what I'm looking to do is return a version of the df that has NaNs in the lower, right-hand side below the "lower-left to upper-right" diagonal.

So desired output would be this:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
A   0   8.0 9.0 4.0 5.0
B   3   4.0 5.0 0.0 NaN
C   8   5.0 5.0 NaN NaN
D   8   5.0 NaN NaN NaN
E   7   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I've found several answers on assigning specific values up the diagonal, but nothing quite like this.

**Working solution:**

As I mentioned, I did get a very clunky solution together, but I'm hoping someone has a much cleaner way to do this. Here is what I have done:

```
In [4]: check_digit_max = df.columns[-1] # the columns are ints, so just get the highest value
In [5]: df['check_digit'] = [i for i,x in enumerate(df.index)]
```

So now I have this:

```
In  [6]: df
Out [6]:
0   1   2   3   4   check_digit
A   0   8   9   4   5   0
B   3   4   5   0   1   1
C   8   5   5   4   1   2
D   8   5   3   8   3   3
E   7   2   6   7   2   4
```

So basically if the column number plus the check digit is greater than the check_*digit_*max, the values should be NaN. And this messy loop does the trick:

```
In  [7]: for col in df.iloc[:,:-1].columns:
            df[col] = [x if int(col)+y <= check_digit_max else np.nan
                   for x,y in zip(df[col], df['check_digit'])]
In  [8]: df.drop('check_digit',axis=1)
Out [8]:
    0   1   2   3   4
A   0   8.0 9.0 4.0 5.0
B   3   4.0 5.0 0.0 NaN
C   8   5.0 5.0 NaN NaN
D   8   5.0 NaN NaN NaN
E   7   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Hopefully someone has a much better way of doing this. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you  can use [`numpy.tril_indices_from`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices_from.html#numpy-tril-indices-from) for the task:

```py
mask = np.zeros_like(df, dtype=bool)
mask[np.tril_indices_from(mask, k=-1)] = True

df[np.flip(mask, 1)] = np.nan
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   0    1    2    3    4
A  4  5.0  1.0  9.0  6.0
B  3  2.0  7.0  6.0  NaN
C  3  2.0  4.0  NaN  NaN
D  1  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
E  3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I need to get more familiar with numpy.

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple mask checking the i/j indices:

```
mask = (np.arange(df.shape[0])[:,None]
       +np.arange(df.shape[1])) < min(df.shape)

out = df.where(mask)
```

For in place modification:

```
mask = (np.arange(df.shape[0])[:,None]
       +np.arange(df.shape[1])) >= min(df.shape)

df[mask] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
   0    1    2    3    4
A  0  1.0  6.0  8.0  1.0
B  2  3.0  2.0  6.0  NaN
C  2  6.0  9.0  NaN  NaN
D  0  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
E  3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

*NB. If the shape of the DataFrame is not square you have to choose what you consider the diagonal and eventually compare to `max(df.shape)`.*

```
# min(df.shape)
   0    1    2    3   4
A  7  0.0  7.0  8.0 NaN
B  1  4.0  2.0  NaN NaN
C  8  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN
D  6  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN

# max(df.shape)
   0  1    2    3    4
A  7  0  7.0  8.0  2.0
B  1  4  2.0  9.0  NaN
C  8  1  2.0  NaN  NaN
D  6  1  NaN  NaN  NaN
```